# Textwatcher doesn't recognize space

Tags: android, search, gridview, editbox

I am trying to filter a gridview and for that I am entering the data in an editbox. It works great except that when I insert a space character in editbox it somehow doesn't recognize it and the result set comes empty. Please help

Here is my editbox listener:

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {

        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

        }

});
```

I can't figure out the problem since it's working fine with other characters.

Comment: is onTextChanged called?

Comment: Yes it's been called when I enter text in in editbox

Comment: try my answer you need to make filter for that

Comment: I tried but how do I put it in my filter for search

Comment: see my edit it will help you to how to make custom filter in adapter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `trim()`. Hope it will work for you.I know you will need to modify this code.but it may give you some idea.

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(search.getText().toString().trim());

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

});
```

If this doesnt work try second option

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
       String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
    if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
         ed.setText(result);
         ed.setSelection(result.length());
         // alert the user
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
            int count) {


        }

});
```

I prefer first option using `trim()`  to string text.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked. But now it doesn't recognize the word after space. Like if I put "Fighting child labor" it only recognizes fighting and the space after it but doesn't recognize child.

Comment: try adding maxlength to your edittext.Its just one suggestion,may not be perfect solution in your case.

Comment: @Zonera how did u solved ur issue listed in ur comment above?by max length?

Answer (score 0):

Move Your filter code to `afterTextChanged()` method.

For example:

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(search.getText().toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

});
```

Comment: Still it returns the empty result on pressing space

Comment: You can try to get text from TextView directly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem with the following code:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    String keywords = editable.toString();
    if (keywords.length() > 0){
        String ultimo = keywords.substring(keywords.length() - 1);
        if (ultimo.equals(" ")){
            youtubeSearchView.setText(editable.toString() + "\b");
            youtubeSearchView.setSelection(keywords.length());
        }
    }
```