# Text change on Space key of keyboard

Tags: java, android

I have made an android app.I'm using google translate API in that and I want some action on my space key of a soft keyboard.When a user enters some text in Text Input the text gets translated into space click.Please help me out there!

**My code** :

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.e("main", "KeyPress:" + actionId);
            if (event != null) {
                Log.e("main", "KeyPress:" + event.getKeyCode());
            }
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                // do 'nothing' or 'add a space' if you want that
                TranslateOptions options = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setApiKey(API_KEY).build();
                Translate translate = options.getService();
                inputText = editText.getText().toString();
                Translation translation = translate.translate(inputText, Translate.TranslateOption.targetLanguage("hi"));
                editText.setText(translation.getTranslatedText());
                Log.e("trans ", " lang " + editText);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. do you want to detect SPACE key on your EditText? In that case, I'd recommend you to use TextWatcher

Comment: i want my text gets transalted when user hit space key of softkeyboard android

Comment: use Textwatcher 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706678/textwatcher-doesnt-recognize-sp